Is it safe to pass a lambda that is going out of scope by reference?
There are similar questions around:

Is it safe to pass a lambda that is going out of scope "by value"?

Yes, because the closure gets copied/moved


Should I pass a lambda by const reference?

Yes, that's useful to avoid copying the state. But you can't pass a mutable lambda, which has a non-const operator()



My question is a mix of the two:
There is a storage class that takes a lambda by reference and somehow stores that, with a method signature like in the linked question:
template <class Function>
void storeCallback(const Function& f)

Is it safe to call it in the following way?
void foo(Storage& o) {
  o.storeCallback([](){std::cout << "hi!";});
}

void bar(Storage& o){
  o.callCallback();
}

The risk I see is that the lambda goes out of scope once foo returns. So the reference would be invalid when, at some point in the future, the stored callback is called?
In the specific case I am interested in, which prompted this question, the specifics of how the lambda is stored in the storage class are, that it is passed to another method which takes a std::function by value as parameter. Does this conversion from reference to std::function somehow make it safe? Or was it already safe independent of how it's stored?
The std::function docs state

Instances of std::function can store, copy, and invoke any CopyConstructible Callable target -- functions (via pointers thereto), lambda expressions, bind expressions, or other function objects, as well as pointers to member functions and pointers to data members.

This sounds to me like the std::function makes it safe because it copies the lambda anyway, even if it was passed by reference.

This is impossible to answer in general (depends on how exactly you store the lambda). If you store it in std::function then you're safe, it always stores a copy.

if you want to use something you need to make sure its still alive by the time you want to use it. Neither are lambdas special with regard to this nor does passing it by reference to a function change something about that. Once you made a copy from a reference you cannot tell the difference between that copy and one made from the object itself (patholoigically broken classes aside)

I have recently open-sourced a much better alternative to std::function. Both in terms of safety, ease of use, performance and configurability. Take a look here

In the code you have written, you are definitely using some kind of type erasure (like std::function) because you are storing unknown type (lambda). If this storage was std::function indeed, you are guaranteed to have a copy of your lambda. This is because copying into std::function would happen before foo goes out of scope. If your storage was saving a reference to your lambda instead of copying it, like std::function_ref does, this would cause undefined behavior. Note, however, that because your lambda does not capture anything, this would most likely give you a correct result even though the behavior is actually undefined.
Also, do not confuse capturing by reference with passing by reference. The latter is usually safe, the former is usually not. If you had this,
void foo(Storage& o) {
  std::string name = "Greta";
  o.storeCallback([&name](){std::cout << "hi! " << name;});
}

the reference to name would dangle. It can be even more dangerous if you are capturing by reference within a member function because you can accidentally capture this by reference and that is UB waiting to happen.

" you are definitely using some kind of type erasure (like std::function) because you are storing unknown type (lambda)." <- That's not true. OP could be using templates, and the templating could have static/global storage.

But foo is called on runtime. How could you then store [](){std::cout << "hi!";} into a global static variable? Could you give an example?

Yes, the library I am using is using std::function - but only one function call further behind the public API, which is more generic (uses templates). Thanks for answering!

@patrick: You template on the function parameter, meaning that each lamda calls a different instantiation of the template, with a different static variable for storing things - which knows the exact type of what it's storing, so no need for type erasure. I'm not saying that's what OP does, just that it's possible.

@einpoklum Sorry, I still do not see how would that be possible. If there is no type-erasure, how does the caller of lambda store the lambda on runtime? Could you please provide a minimal working example because I am not following you?
